# Jasmine-node assertions within promises not shown

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, jasmine-node

The below code all functions correctly with the exception of the assertion. When the test is run Jasmine reports 0 assertions.  How can I keep my assertions within the promises and have them be recognized?

```
it("should open save NTP server modal", function (done) {
    var addModal = driver.findElement(By.className('modal-dialog'));
    driver.wait(until.stalenessOf(addModal), 5000).then(function () {
        return     driver.wait(until.elementIsEnabled(driver.findElement(By.id('saveButton'))), 5000).then(function (element){ 
            return element.click();
        });
    });

    driver.findElement(By.className("modal-body")).then(function (element) {
        return expect(element.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
    });

    done();
});
```

I know that in this specific case(my best example test) I could just catch the element and then do the expect outside of a promise:

```
var element = driver.findElement(By.className("modal-body"));
expect(element.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
```

Unfortunately I have other cases where I cannot determine a way to do the exception outside of a promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your "done" method inside the final callback.

```
driver.findElement(By.className("modal-body")).then(function (element) {
    expect(element.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
    done();
});
```

You can also look into Chai promises library, which is meant for handling async expects.

Comment: Also if you have asserts waiting for multiple promise objects to resolve then it would be better to use libraries like async.js to properly call the "done" callback.

Comment: This was the issue thanks!  I'll take a look at using mocha/chai again and see if it would be better.